# redirect specific url for mobile devices

Tags: .htaccess, mobile, redirect, device

first post here ;-)

My question. How do I redirect mobile visitors, once they view a specific url within my website, to the mobile version of that specific url?

For example a mobile device user visits **mydomain.com/thisurl** then that url should be redirected only for mobile device users to **mydomain/thisurl_mobile**.

I have partly some htaccess code that might be a start? But not sure how to do this for a specific url? This is what I have so far (Btw it needs to be https):

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# only detect smart phone devices if we are not on mobile site
# to prevent redirect looping
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop

# a bunch of smart phone devices
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sony|symbian|nokia|samsung|mobile" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "windows ce|epoc|opera|mini|nitro" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "j2me|midp-|cldc-|netfront|mot" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up\.browser|up\.link|audiovox" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "mini|nitro|j2me|midp-|cldc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "netfront|mot|up\.browser|up\.link"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "audiovox|blackberry|ericsson,"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "panasonic|philips|sanyo|sharp|sie-"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "portalmmm|blazer|avantgo|dange"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|series60|palmsource|pocketpc"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "smartphone|rover|ipaq|au-mic,"[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "alcatel|ericy|vodafone\/|wap1\."[NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wap2\.|iPhone|android"[NC,OR]

# redirect google mobile bot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "googlebot-mobile"[NC]

# if the request is from any one of the above devices
# redirect to mobile url
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.mydomain/thisurl_mobile [L,R=302]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The issue is the actual rule condefined: `RewriteRule ^$  ...`. The `^$` will only match an empty request path. Why that limitation?

Comment: @arkascha So i should remove the ^$?

But the htaccess file should know when to redirect **mydomain.com/thisurl** to **mydomain/thisurl_mobile** for mobile device visitors only. How would I implement that? As of now the htaccess file redirects every mobile visitor for the whole domain to **mydomain/thisurl_mobile** isn't it? It should only redirect mobile visitors when they visit **mydomain.com/thisurl** to -> **mydomain/thisurl_mobile**.